# Meaning of Long in JPARepository?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What is `Long` here and what on basis do we configure this in `JpaRepository`?

```
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, Long> {
}
```

Comment: and what does that have to do with the JPA API (as opposed to Spring Data JPA) ...

Comment: I don't see `long` and what is even your question? Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 8):

Long is data type of Primary key (RDBMS) or autogenerated unique document Id(Mongo DB).

```
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityName,DataType_of_primaryKey> {

}
```

Ex:
If your Entity is like that:

```
class Person{
   Long id;
   String name;
}
```

```
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {
}
```

**Exmplanation**

**Person** -> Entity

**id** -> Primary key for Person object(Data type should be **long**)

Comment: thank you. I had this confusion you solved it. Thanks again